# Getting JavaScript code errors, can anyone help me?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am getting a few errors within JavaScript. I am fairly new at JavaScript/Jquery. I have checked the errors over google and I understand the errors, however they still appear after attempting to troubleshoot these problems....

Errors are shown on this link:
[JavaScript Console Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTWin.png)

**I have tried -** Changing file directories, - changing file names, - adding JQuery CDN as first point of call in HTML as expected,-  adding a Local Jquery file, - Adding Particles.js and Typed.Js in body tags, adding the js code within body.

**HTML Code shown below:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta lang="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/c0nsec.min.css">
  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/particles.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/typed.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/c0nsec.min.js"></script>
  <!-- My own js file -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="particles-js"></div>
  <!-- For full body paricles -->

  <div class="container">
    <section class="mainLanding">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <h1 class="test"> ELLO WORLD M8</h1>
          <div class="center">
            <!-- For typed.js plugin -->
            <span class="type"></span>
          </div>
    </section>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS code shown Below:**

```
/*======================*/


/* DEFAULT TEMPLATE*/


/*======================*/

html {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Sans-Serif;
}

body {
  background: #1f1f1f;
}


/* Particles JS  tag */

#particles-js {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/*======================*/


/* HEADER */


/*======================*/


/*======================*/


/* HEADINGS */


/*======================*/

.test {
  font-family: Source Sans Pro;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 7vh;
}


/*======================*/


/* SECTIONS */


/*======================*/

.mainLanding {
  position: relative;
  top: 50vh;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}


/* Typed JS tags */

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.center span {
  font-family: Source Sans Pro;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #fff;
}
```

**JavaScript code shown below:**

```
// Custom Typed.js scripts
$(function() {
  $(".type").typed({
    strings: [
      "Hello World",
      "We are C0nSec, we consult with security vulnerabilites",
      "Our mission is to keep the internet safe from criminals"
    ],
    typeSpeed: 70,
    backDelay: 200,
    loop: true
  })
})
```

Comment: Don't take screenshots of errors. Just copy the error message.

Comment: Maybe import jQuery before everything else (which uses it).

Comment: First, move the jQuery script tag to the top of the list and your own file (I'm guessing app.js) to the bottom.

Your JavaScript code has one more opening parenthesis than it has closing parenthesis, so check that as well.

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Use jsfiddle or codepen to demonstrate your issue.